# can't set the proper file permission for php file upload

Tags: php, linux

I know that there are a lot of similar questions, but just hear me out and if this was a silly question and there was nothing new about it, i'll just delete this question.

I'm trying to upload using php, but I get permission denied. So here's what I did to solve it and didn't work:

first of all, this is localhost, so i can't set the owner of the files to apache, because I won't be able to edit them.
So I got the apache user name in php, and it was www-data

I created a new group called 'localhostowners'

I added my own user to this group

I added www-data to the group

when I run

```
grep -i 'localhostowners' /etc/group
```

I get

```
localhostowners:x:1001:mnvoh,www-data
```

And then I set the file permissions for everything on the localhost dir to 764
and set the owner with this:

```
sudo chown -R mnvoh:localhostowners localhostdir
```

But now I can't execute the php scripts hence the 4. although according to what I know, the 6 should be affecting apache, since I set the group on the files. What am I doing wrong here???

Thanks everybody :)

Comment: Try chmod g+w localhostdir

Comment: No, Unfortunately that didn't work. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

Test with:

```
sudo chown -R mnvoh:localhostowners localhostdir
sudo chmod 764 -R localhostdir
```

-R: recursivity

Comment: Thanks Jose, I've done all the chown and chmod recursively, I just forgot to include it in the question. alhough I'm moving the uploaded file to localhostdir itself

Answer (score -1):

First you should check the permission the file

```
ls -a
```

or

```
ll
```

and make sure the person who want to execute the file have X permission.

```
-user-group-other
-rwx  rwx   rwx
```